# Class 'Craft\File' not found during installation

Tags: error-message, craft2, install, installation, files

I'm installing Craft 2 locally and am getting this error message when I expect the installation screen.  I've checked the write permissions, and the directory has them (inheritable permissions).  Thanks

```
Fatal error: Class 'Craft\File' not found in craft\app\helpers\IOHelper.php on line 727
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're missing some required Craft 2 files.

Try [downloading a fresh copy](http://craftcms.com/latest-v2.zip) of the latest Craft 2 and replace your existing `app` folder with a fresh `app` folder from the download.